# Understanding the condition of the bounded variable algorithm in the linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, bounds

Following is the section 7.3 of **Operation Research An Introduction by Hamdy A. Taha**,

Define the upper-bounded LP model as, $$\max z=\{CX|(A,I)X=b,0\leq X\leq U\}$$
The bounded algorithm uses only the main constraints $(A,I)X=b,X\geq0$. It accounts for the upper bounds, $X\leq U$, implicitly by modifying the feasibility condition.

Let $\mathbf{X}_B=\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{b}$ be a current basic feasible solution of $(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{I}) \mathbf{X}=\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{X} \geq \mathbf{0}$, and assume that $\mathbf{P}_j$ is the entering vector (as determined by the regular optimality condition). Then, given that all the nonbasic variables are zero, the constraint equation of the $i$ th basic variable is
$$
\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_i=\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{b}\right)_i-\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{P}_j\right)_i x_j
$$
When the entering variable $x_j$ increases above zero level, $\left(\mathbf{X}_{\boldsymbol{B}}\right)_i$ will increase or decrease depending on whether $\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{P}_j\right)_i$ is negative or positive, respectively. Thus, in determining the value of the entering vector $\mathbf{P}_j$, three conditions must be satisfied:

1. The basic variable remains nonnegative - that is, $\left(\mathbf{X}_{\boldsymbol{B}}\right)_i \geq 0$.
2. The basic variable $\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_i$ does not exceed its upper bound-that is, $\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_i \leq\left(\mathbf{U}_B\right)_i$, where $\mathbf{U}_B$ comprises the elements of $\mathbf{U}$ corresponding to $\mathbf{X}_B$.
3. The entering variable $x_j$ cannot assume a value larger than its upper bound-that is, $x_j \leq \mathrm{u}_j$, where $u_j$ is the $j$ th element of $\mathbf{U}$.

The first condition $\left(\mathbf{X}_{\boldsymbol{B}}\right)_i \geq 0$ is the same as in the regular simplex method. It yields
$$
x_j \leq \theta_1=\min _i\left\{\frac{\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{b}\right)_i}{\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{P}_j\right)_i} \mid\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{P}_j\right)_i>0\right\}
$$
The second condition $\left(\mathbf{X}_{\boldsymbol{B}}\right)_i \leq\left(\mathbf{U}_{\boldsymbol{B}}\right)_i$ specifies that
$$
\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{b}\right)_i-\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{P}_j\right)_i x_j \leq\left(\mathbf{U}_B\right)_i
$$
It is satisfied if
$$
x_j \leq \theta_2=\min _i\left\{\frac{\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{b}\right)_i-\left(\mathbf{U}_B\right)_i}{\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{P}_j\right)_i} \mid\left(\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{P}_j\right)_i<0\right\}
$$
Combining the three restrictions, $x_j$ enters the solution at the level that satisfies all three conditions-that is,
$$
x_j=\min \left\{\theta_1, \theta_2, u_j\right\}
$$

> **Question:** I couldn't understand why we need to include $u_j$ in $x_j=\min \left\{\theta_1, \theta_2, u_j\right\}$ as we already consider the $\mathbf{U}_B$ in case 2? Maybe I am not clear how they are using upper bound $U$ in these two cases.

The change of basis for the next iteration depends on whether $x_j$ enters the solution at level $\theta_1, \theta_2$, or $u_j$. Assuming that $\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_r$ is the leaving variable, then we have the following rules:

1. $x_j=\theta_1:\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_r$ leaves the basic solution (becomes nonbasic) at level zero. The new iteration is generated using the regular simplex method with $x_j$ and $\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_r$ as the entering and the leaving variables, respectively.
2. $x_j=\theta_2:\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_r$ becomes nonbasic at its upper bound. The new iteration is generated as in the case of $x_j=\theta_1$, with one modification that accounts for the fact that $\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_r$ will be nonbasic at upper bound. Because the values of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ require all nonbasic variables to be at zero level (convince yourself that this is the case!), the new nonbasic $\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_r$ at upper bound is converted to a nonbasic variable at zero level. This is achieved by using the substitution $\left(\mathbf{X}_B\right)_r=\left(\mathbf{U}_B\right)_r-\left(\mathbf{X}_B^{\prime}\right)_r$, where $\left(\mathbf{X}_B^{\prime}\right)_r \geq 0$. It is immaterial whether the substitution is made before or after the new basis is computed.
3. $x_j=u_j$ : The basic vector $\mathbf{X}_B$ remains unchanged because $x_j=u_j$ stops short of forcing any of the current basic variables to reach its lower $(=0)$ or upper bound. This means that $x_j$ will remain nonbasic but at upper bound. The only change needed in the tableau is to use the substitution $x_j=u_j-x_j^{\prime}$ to ensure that all nonbasic variables are at zero level.

> **Question:** I manage to understand the three conditions above, but couldn't directly see how the procedure mentioned for $x_j=\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and $x_j=u_j$ resolving the issue (force $x_j$ to satisfy the condition).

It will be a great help if anyone enlighten me the intuition or redirect me to any great resources. Do I need to split this question into several thread as it seems big enough? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do I need to modify the question? As I am not getting any answer yet. It will be a great help if anyone give me further suggestion, please.

Comment: If you have the bounded variables, why not try to add these bounds as the constraints to the original model and go ahead with Simplex?

Comment: I can add lower bound, but adding upper bound might not resolve the issue. That's the book illustrated, @A.Omidi

Comment: Try take a look at Section 3.4.1 in  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228791187_Linear_optimization_Theory_methods_and_extensions